# How do i make it so an enemy sprite follows the player sprite in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser 3

```
create(){
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'player');
        this.enemy = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'enemy');
        this.physics.moveToObject(this.enemy, this.player, 100);
}
```

So far i have this but because i'm using this.physics.add.sprite and not this.physics.add.image it doesn't work.

I specifically need to use this.physics.add.sprite

editted:

```
enemyFollows () {
        this.enemy.x = this.player.body.position.x;
        this.enemy.y = this.player.body.position.y;
    }
```

Now using this but need to have it slowly moving to player's body position.

Comment: What do you mean with "It doesn't work"? Is there any error in console, or the sprite does not appear on screen?

Comment: Because it's not an object. But i currently changed it so that it follows the player, but now it sticks to the player. so far i have this `enemyFollows () {
        this.enemy.x = this.player.body.position.x;
        this.enemy.y = this.player.body.position.y;
    }`

Now i need to slowly move the enemy to the player's body position. Slowly meaning with a slow velocity. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.

```
enemyFollows () {
        this.physics.moveToObject(this.enemy, this.player, 100);
    }
```

I didn't put it in the create() function but made a new function for it and called the enemyFollows() in the update()

like this

```
update() {
this.enemyFollows();
}
```